# Qualification required to become a Software Tester

Tags: manual-testing, interview, qualification

One of my friend wants to start career in Software Testing. I have suggested him to join some software testing classes and take ISTQB foundation level certification.

But the thing is he has qualification , **12th + diploma in IT** and also he is doing some kind of network support work since 3 year in a non IT firm.

I'm not sure that above qualification accepted for Software Tester job role?

Suppose he has done certification and will have required skill then will it be comfortable to get a job after these many years of gap ?

Can someone please suggest ?

Comment: What does it mean to have "qualification as 12th"?

Comment: he has completed `diploma in IT after 12th`

Comment: Ahhh, 12th = US name for completing high school

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of [Fundamental Requirements For an Entry Level QA Engineer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/3238/25505) which is the closest I could find to a canonical answer on "how do I get into QA with no experience in that field". There are a number of questions about getting into QA coming from field/experience X but I think the answers there apply regardless of background, and are more useful than whether or not to get a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Software testing qualification is not only testing knowledge but also the areas around the context that will be tested. For example to add the best value in testing financial applications will be knowledge of finances also. Not only software. 
The skills should be adjusted to the position that he is going to apply to, but I can agree that the fundamental knowledge is in ISTQB Foundation Level Syllabus. There's no need to make a certificate (unless it's required in a particular company) but to have a good knowledge of the topics from syllabus.

Answer (score 0):

Qualifications to start working in QA will vary from one job offer to another, depending on skills required for a specific position and how high is demand vs. supply of people with specific skills on your local job market. For instance, in cities where it is harder to find a good QA companies might decide to employ lower qualified people and train them later.

To get a real picture of how it is in your friend's location I would  browse through job offers in his location. They usually say what experience and education are required. For instance, whether ISTQB certification is useful depends on a specific company -- see separate questions:

- [Do ISTQB/ISEB Testing Certificates prove that someone can test?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/do-istqb-iseb-testing-certificates-prove-that-someone-can-test) and
- [Will getting a Software Testing Certification benefit me in my career?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9969/will-getting-a-software-testing-certification-benefit-me-in-my-career?rq=1).